# Why is the objective in a multi-armed bandit problems to minimize (cumulative) regret?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In a multi-armed bandit, the objective is to maximize the expected cumulative reward. This objective is usually (equivalently?) stated in terms of expected cumulative regret.

**Question:** Why not just deal with the reward? Why formulate the objective in terms of regret?